# Shell Closing when starting on Windows and adding new lines

Tags: python

I'm new to code and i have a doubt that i did not find anywhere else. When i try to open a file .py using the Python Shell (double click on Windows) it closes. It's not a code problem because i've created a new file, added this line:

```
print("test")
```

and the same thing happended. The most stranger thing is that if i press F5 at the editor, everything works fine. The other thing is that with another file, when i press F5 in the editor, the code works fine but adds a lot of new lines before the code (i did not add any new lines to the code). You can see this code that i'm talking about [***here***](https://pastebin.com/jiMYWRzq) and the module [***here***](https://pastebin.com/5JXKb5EZ) or you can see all the code at [***GitHub***](https://github.com/feRpicoral/Biologia/tree/master/main)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean you're just double clicking the `.py` file, you see the shell blink into existence for a moment, then disappear, that's expected. A shell is created to run `python` to run the script, the script runs to completion, then exits, and the shell (no longer having a running program in it) closes as well.

If you want the output to stick around, either:

1. Launch a `cmd.exe` window directly, and invoke your program from there (since the `cmd.exe` window won't exit, the output will stick around), or
2. Add a call that prevents the program from exiting until you've had a chance to read the output to the end of your program, e.g. `input('Press Enter key to exit...')` or the like. As long as that `input` prompt doesn't get a response, the program is still running, and you can see the output.

Answer (score 0):

The .py file closes immediately because it finishes its execution and exits upon the call of SystemExit. The whole process is too fast for you to be able to see the output on the console. If you want to execute a .py file without using the editor and be able to see the output as well, you can try using cmd and execute a line like this

```
python yourfile.py
```

In this way, the window will be left open until you manually close it. However, you have to setup properly to be able to use this python command in cmd, and it is very easy as you can search up online.

For second question, it is because you have printed `\n` 101 times at line 6 & 7. All function/method calls will be executed at the time you have called them. It does not mean that you can assign a function to a variable, and then only execute the function when you call the variable.

Every function will execute its code and return you something (as what has specified using return statement, can be void too). So if you assign a variable `x` to a `print("\n")` statement, it will print `\n` first and return void(nothing) back to your variable `x`.